# Tableau subtotal in graph

Tags: tableau-api, desktop

I am trying to make a graph/chart of showing a measure category-wise.  The categories are further subdivided into sub-categories and these sub-category has also been added in the view.

What I am trying to achieve is to include category wise measure sub-total in the view but as a label only.  If I am adding sub-totals from analysis pane, another bar is added which I do not want.  I only want that these sub-total values be displayed as a label under each category.

How should I proceed?
For this purpose sample superstore data on tableau may be considered.

Comment: Please add a screenshot, so that it could be understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some workaround to show it like this.

step-1 added a desired 'sub-total' field like this (Sample -superstore data in tableau)

```
{Fixed [Category]: SUM([Sales])}
```

Created a view thereafter like this, which in my opinion should serve your purpose

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, yes you have been right, I needed to add one more calculated field.

Comment: Glad that my solution served your purpose.  Though not compulsory your votes will be highly appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote